# Mui's ToggleButtonGroup with yup conditional validation in react app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I have this condition in my yup schema:

```
const schema = yup
  .object({
    format: yup.string(),
    recipient_email: yup.string().email().when('format', {
      is: (value) => (value === 'email'),
      then: yup.string().required(I18n.t('is_required'))
    }),

  })
  .required();
```

Then the ToggleButtonGroup:

```
          <Controller
            name="format"
            control={control}
            render={( field ) => (
              <ToggleButtonGroup
                color="primary"
                {...register('format')}
                value={generateFormat}
                exclusive
                fullWidth={true}
                color={'success'}
              >
                <ToggleButton 
                  value="print"
                  onClick={() => toggleFormat('print')}
                >
                  {I18n.t('new_gift__format_print')}
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton 
                  value="email" 
                  onClick={() => toggleFormat('email')}
                >
                  {I18n.t('new_gift__format_email')}
                </ToggleButton>
              </ToggleButtonGroup>
            )}
          />
```

So I this `onClick={() => toggleFormat('email')` is setting the react hook state `generateFormat`, and what I want is the validation to work when this state is selected, so when I submit the form it validates the email field (if the state is set as 'email'):

```
                  <Controller
                    name="recipient_email"
                    control={control}
                    rules={{ required: true }}
                    render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
                      <Input
                        {...field}
                        id="receiver_email"
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="email@email.com"
                        innerRef={ref}
                        className={errors.email && 'error'}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
```

Comment: did you use `mode` when you call useForm? like this `useForm({ mode: 'all'})`

Comment: nope, i have it as

```useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  }); ```

Comment: `mode` option allows you to configure the validation strategy before user submit the form

Comment: I'll give it a check